# Root cause of FIS_AUTH_ERROR

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I work on team that has "established" native Android app. We use firebase messaging for sending push notifications.

We also have a process where we refresh the push notification token. What we have seen is when attempting to refresh the token, we see large number of FIS_AUTH_ERROR exception.

We are using the latest fcm library version - 23.2.1

For last 30 days we attempted to refreshe token 259385963 times, and refresh attempts failed 298790 times -- just for data sake we found 7657 times new token we got was "different" from what we had i.e. we needed new token 7657 times.

Shown below is the breakdown of exceptions.

Question is -- What is the reason for such a large number of FIS_AUTH_ERROR exceptions? As app developer what should we be checking?

Also tangential question, is there a way to report this issue to firebase team?

```
FIS_AUTH_ERROR           30328
SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE    29862
INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR      127
AUTHENTICATION_FAILED       74
TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS      66
PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR    47
MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE   2
```